# C# Storing Declaration and Type Pattern Result Causes CS0165 (Use of Unassigned Local Variable)

Tags: c#, variable-declaration

I'm curious why both of the following code segments produces *error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'i'*:

```
// Attempt #1
object obj = 4;
bool isInt = obj is int i;
if (isInt)
    Console.WriteLine("obj = {0}", i); // CS0165

// Attempt #2
object obj = 4;
bool isInt;
if (isInt = obj is int i)
    Console.WriteLine("obj = {0}", i); // CS0165
```

The following compiles, but seems like it shouldn't be necessary:

```
object obj = 4;
bool isInt = false;
if (obj is int i)
{
    isInt = true;
    Console.WriteLine("obj = {0}", i);
}
```

Is there a less verbose way to use C# Declaration and Type Patterns when attempting to store the result of the test condition?

Comment: Depending on what you need the result of the test condition for, you can skip the assignment of the boolean entirely and just perform your logic in your `if` statement. Like:

`object obj = 4;
if (obj is int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("obj = {0}", i);

   // perform other logic here for the int value
}`